# the marker is added after the second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display markers after entering x and y, and read this data from the table. I have 2 inputs, one for X and the other for Y after clicking "add" I add this data to the table and I have 2 objects, etc ... but markers are added after the second click and should be added after the first click

```
state={
items:[{
      "X": 13.6155611,
      "Y": 51.0331258
    },
    ],
} 

componentDidMount() {
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [13, 51],
      zoom: 6
    })
 for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }
}

addItem = (e) => {
    const newItem = {
      "Y": parseFloat(this.state.X),
      "X": parseFloat(this.state.Y),
}
 this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
    }));
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [13, 51],
      zoom: 6
    })
 for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }
e.preventDefault();
}
render() {
    return (
        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} />

<form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
 <input
              type="number"
              value={this.state.X}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                X: e.target.value
              })}
            />
            <input
              value={this.state.Y}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                Y: e.target.value
              })}
            />
 <button>ADD</button>
</form>
)}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure that you provide us with a Minimal Reproducible Example so we can appropriately help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running `for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++)`, state hasn't been updated with the newItem you added yet. When the function is created, it only knows about the existing state.

Try something like

```js
const newItems = [...this.state.items, newItem]
this.setState(newItems);

// ...

for (const obj of newItems) {
  const myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
  new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(myLatlng)
    .addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: thanks it helped, can you get rid of page reloading?